# What keywords are legal inside Type.GetType()?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm confused with the documentation

```
public class Framework
{
    public StreamReader Reader;
    public CsvReader Csv;
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public DataTable Table;

    public Framework()
    {
        //Path = "file.csv";
        //Reader = new StreamReader(Path);
        //Csv = new CsvReader(Reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string[] ColumnNames = { "Name", "Phone", "Address" };
        Table = CreateTable(ColumnNames);
    }

    //args are the name of the columns
    public DataTable CreateTable(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
        DataRow row;

        /* create columns */

        column.DataType = Type.GetType("Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "ID";
        tbl.Columns.Add(column);

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("String");
            column.ColumnName = args[i];
            tbl.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        row = tbl.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = 1;
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);

        return tbl;
    }
}
```

The debugger tells me that `GetType()` does not recognize the `'String'`
I read I could do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netcore-3.1#retrieving-a-type-object).
This program is a .net framework proyect and all it does at the end is to display a `datagridview` with a button click function that only has `dataGridView1.DataSource = Framework.Table;`
the program doesn't even show, what I am doing wrong? I feel there's zero information about this...

Comment: GetType can be brittle, the string parameter should be the assembly-qualified name of the type, however it will take shorter forms, though there are many reasons why it will fail on the shorter variants

Comment: Give like this column.DataType = typeof(Int32);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write the full name of the type, i.e.

```
column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
```

If you always want to get the string type, you can also write

```
column.DataType = typeof(string);
```

Use your method where you use a string to get the type's name only if you don't know during compile time which type you need.

Comment: then why does it should work with  `Int32` if it needs the  `System.`

Comment: This is not really the complete story, but probably good enough for an answer to this particular question

Comment: @EgonStetmann.To be honest, I don't know why it works with `Int32`. But I strongly recommend that you use the `typeof` operator. It has many advantages, e.g. you will realize spelling errors more easily, or if you use it on your own type, it is easier to rename this type.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Type t = typeof(string)` or `Type.GetType("System.String")` or `typof(int).Assembly.GetType("System.String")`

Answer (score 0):

Give like this `column.DataType = typeof(Int32);`